# Spyder IDE Console and Filename fonts are super huge

Tags: spyder

I opened Spyder IDE (Anaconda) and found that the console font and icons are super huge (see image).[Spyder IDE font is huge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU7AO.png)

I tried looking through Preferences but couldn't find anything to reset things to normal.

Thanks for the help

I tried modifying the DPI as suggested here:https://superuser.com/questions/1473131/control-font-size-of-spyder-python-ide-on-everything-except-the-editor-code

But that still leaves the same result.

Comment: Could you try the answer in this link - https://superuser.com/questions/1473131/control-font-size-of-spyder-python-ide-on-everything-except-the-editor-code?

Comment: @AnindyaDey thank you for the suggestion. I tried modifying the DPI but that still keep the font ratio of the editor to the console window the same.